# Unable to host a server with Xpra, only connect to an existing one

Tags: x11, x-server, xpra

I've downloaded and installed Xpra from [their distribution hosted on winswitch](http://winswitch.org/dists/generic-rpm/). However, when I try to run it on my server I'm getting:

> This xpra install does not support starting local servers.

and indeed, it won't accept the `start` mode, only the `attach` mode. What am I doing wrong, and how can I host an xpra session after all?

Running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago), Linux version 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I've been using the "generic" RPMs hoping it would just work, but it doesn't. "totaam" from winswitch chat helped me realize that, and turned me to [the correct RPMs for my distribution](http://winswitch.org/dists/CentOS/). It now works fine.

Comment: For those wondering why that is: when using the wrong RPMs, some of the shared libraries will not load (or will be completely missing in the case of the generic RPMs) and this prevents you from using the server which requires them - but not the client.